# Installing counterclockwise plugin on eclipse fails

Tags: java, eclipse, clojure

After struggling with this whole day I think its better to ask help from forums like this. Im trying to install ccw plugin to eclipse, but I get this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Counterclockwise Feature 0.0.64.STABLE01 (ccw.feature.feature.group 0.0.64.STABLE01)
  Software being installed: Counterclockwise Feature REPL UI Branch 0.2.0.RC06 (ccw.feature_replui.feature.group 0.2.0.RC06)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Paredit.clj 0.1.1 (paredit.clj 0.1.1)
    Paredit.clj 0.3.0.STABLE (paredit.clj 0.3.0.STABLE)
    Paredit.clj 0.1.5 (paredit.clj 0.1.5)
    Paredit.clj 0.7.0.STABLE (paredit.clj 0.7.0.STABLE)
    Paredit.clj 0.9.0.STABLE01 (paredit.clj 0.9.0.STABLE01)
    Paredit.clj 0.7.1.STABLE (paredit.clj 0.7.1.STABLE)
    Paredit.clj 0.1.0 (paredit.clj 0.1.0)
    Paredit.clj 0.2.1.STABLE (paredit.clj 0.2.1.STABLE)
    Paredit.clj 0.2.0.STABLE (paredit.clj 0.2.0.STABLE)
    Paredit.clj 0.1.4 (paredit.clj 0.1.4)
    Paredit.clj 0.6.0.STABLE (paredit.clj 0.6.0.STABLE)
    Paredit.clj 0.10.0.STABLE01 (paredit.clj 0.10.0.STABLE01)
    Paredit.clj 0.12.1.STABLE01 (paredit.clj 0.12.1.STABLE01)
    Paredit.clj 0.11.0.STABLE01 (paredit.clj 0.11.0.STABLE01)
    Paredit.clj 0.1.3 (paredit.clj 0.1.3)
    Paredit.clj 0.12.5.STABLE01 (paredit.clj 0.12.5.STABLE01)
    Paredit.clj 0.5.0.STABLE (paredit.clj 0.5.0.STABLE)
    Paredit.clj 0.11.1.STABLE01 (paredit.clj 0.11.1.STABLE01)
    Paredit.clj 0.8.0.STABLE (paredit.clj 0.8.0.STABLE)
    Paredit.clj 0.12.0.STABLE01 (paredit.clj 0.12.0.STABLE01)
    Paredit.clj 0.7.2.RC1 (paredit.clj 0.7.2.RC1)
    Paredit.clj 0.1.2 (paredit.clj 0.1.2)
    Paredit.clj 0.7.2.RC2 (paredit.clj 0.7.2.RC2)
    Paredit.clj 0.12.4.STABLE01 (paredit.clj 0.12.4.STABLE01)
    Paredit.clj 0.1.7.stable (paredit.clj 0.1.7.stable)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Counterclockwise Feature 0.0.64.STABLE01 (ccw.feature.feature.group 0.0.64.STABLE01)
    To: paredit.clj [0.11.1.STABLE01]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Counterclockwise Feature REPL UI Branch 0.2.0.RC06 (ccw.feature_replui.feature.group 0.2.0.RC06)
    To: paredit.clj [0.12.4.STABLE01]
```

They say to  manually put antlr jar to solve dependencity problems, but it didnt help me. It must be something too obvious I cant figure out now.

Comment: *How* did you install it - via update site or manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to install both the current stable version and the release candidate. Pick one or the other.

Comment: Thats what I tried at first, then tried using single selection of the release and still got this error. I went to try once more all the four options on install and found that only BETA release worked on my system. After that Eclipse wanted to update plugin libraries which succeed also, so now its working. Thanks for answers and tips for both of you Chris and Chas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall the 0.0.64 version before installing any of the new RC releases.

Also, FYI, there is a user-oriented mailing list for ccw here:

http://groups.google.com/group/clojuredev-users

Comment: I did have any former installs, maybe something was left on machine on dependency check...